# How to use AJAX to display a users mouse pointer on a website so that everyone viewing the website can see it?

Tags: jquery

Ok, I know that sounded a bit confusing, so to better illustrate this:

Imagine we're all on stackoverflow right now (in which we are). How many people are also asking a question right now and typing in the same textarea box that I'm in? I know its possible to show how many users are on a page at a time, but is it possible to use AJAX to show the co-ordinance of users mouse pointers as they move about the page? maybe even their mouse pointers w/ there username by it floating around to where ever they might be clicking (see where I'm going w/ this)?

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're looking for some kind of google docs app model, it will take more than just simple Ajax to do the job (mainly for performance reasons). Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Answer (score 1):

Found this post because I want to do the same thing.  The answer is yes, you can send the position relative to a div and update it every so often, then on the other side update position using transitions.  It won't be accurate, but the goal is to give users the feeling that more people are on the page at the same time.  You could use these divs to show, "user is typing" etc.  For my case I want users to know if a reply is coming or they should leave and come back later.

Comment: Nice! once you get a generic version of it you should definitely post a fiddle of it on here :)  ... when i originally asked this i had an idea for it but the time has passed and i forgot what that idea was haha.. but definitely would be cool to see something like this in action

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing something like this.

What you would have to do is send every movement of the mouse to the server, which would store it in memory with the user's username (and any other details you need). You'd need a persistent connection open to every user's browser (See [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)) so that

1. You don't have to deal with the overhead of establishing a new connection for every update of the mouse position
2. You can push details of other users' mouse positions to all users' browsers.

The reasons this is a bad idea, are

1. Mouse pointer updates would be triggered extremely frequently, and would generate a LOT of Traffic.
2. You have to then send every mouse position update to ALL users currently logged in
3. This constant activity would also slow down users' browsers.

The folks at Google had enough trouble implementing this on Google Wave, and that was mostly with text updates. Unless you have a really important use case where this behavior is important, I would suggest a less network-intensive user interface.

Comment: Is it possible to use new technologies like html5, canvas, and web sockets to produce such an effect???

Comment: Irrespective of whether you use Web Sockets or Comet, there is no difference in the amount of network traffic. That's still extremely high. Canvas is just a drawing framework, so choosing it versus something else has no impact on what you are trying to achieve here.